# HTML table remove padding between specific columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

I have a table which is a bit like this:

```
/---+---+---+---+---+---\
| A | B | C | D | E | F |
\---+---+---+---+---+---/
```

I would like to get A and B to appear visually to be in the same cell, but not actually be in the same cell.

To do this I will need to have the border and padding between A and B become 0px.

However, setting the TD padding (Or margin!) did not work for me. So, any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen If you only want it for a certain row please specify and I will update my code to show you how. Otherwise if you did want it all the way down the first two columns please accept my answer as it should work for you :-)

Comment: oh no! That is quite alright, thank you very much, what you provided should work like a charm, I am just doing research on what you used so that I can understand it and test it myself hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a different solution, and though slightly more complicated than the one previously suggested, I believe it will give you more flexibility as to how to apply the solution.

First, it does require some css code as shown below:

```
td:not([colspan='2']) {
  /*your styling here*/
}
td[colspan='2'] {
  display: table-row;
}
td[colspan='2'] > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  /*same styling here*/
}
```

Finally, the html:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>
        <div id="cell-a"></div>
        <div id="cell-b"></div>
      </td>
      <td id="cell-c"></td>
      <!--and so on-->
```

Basically, the css mimics the table's built-in display in order to optimize the table-row styling. This will allow css to do all the work, and furthermore, will allow you to put a colspan='2' anywhere in order to double up two cells wherever you need. I have already tested locally to ensure that this works.

**Edit:**
Just added the width: 50% under td[colspan='2'] > div in order to space them out properly within the table structure.

Comment: Not to be rude but this is bad style handling, inline styles should try to be avoided and so should tables and table settings like colspan. If someone insists on using tables the best way to help them is not to suggest old ways of doing things that will soon be obsolete (like inline styles/table settings). You can already display:table on divs, you can build whole table systems with just divs, no td, table, tr etc.

Comment: @Event_Horizon I agree with you on the subject of tables vs. divs, however George is already using a table, and has asked for a solution with the use of a table. However, I politely disagree with your inclination towards inline styles, which I believe for certain situations, such as the one George has just provided, is completely acceptable when you need a certain solution in a specific spot.

Comment: Right but what happens if he want's several columns across several files to be merged into one column, your way he is going to have to edit each file and change them, the way I suggested he only has to edit the CSS file which is much easier. In general I think using styles in CSS over inline is always better.

Comment: @Event_Horizon: And when it comes to that, one can easily move the styles into a style sheet.  Til it's gonna be repeated, does it really matter?

Comment: Great solution! This is for a theme which I have been modifying (not creating from scratch) Turns out they used colspan=2 inline anyhow, so no worries! (plus it's only in one spot anyways, the table is PHP generated) I never knew you could even do this, thanks a ton! However, If I needed to, I could see myself using Event_Horizon's method of selecting the elements, and then using CSS to set ColSpan but keeping everything else the same

Answer (score 2):

Using **CSS** this can be quite easy, especially if you want both 1st and 2nd columns always merged looking like below.

`:nth-child(2)` selects the second td of every row in this css
`:first-child` selects the first td of every row in this css, it can also be written as `:nth-child(1)`

#### Code:

```
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;   
}

td
{
padding:4px;
border:1px solid black;   
}

tr td:first-child
{
padding-right:0;
margin-right:0;
border-right:0;
}

tr td:nth-child(n)
{
padding-left:0;
margin-left:0;
border-left:0;   
}
```

#### Example page:

http://jsfiddle.net/h6DWg/1/

#### Edit

OP Requested keeping border un-collapsed, the new example to keep border un-collapsed is at http://jsfiddle.net/h6DWg/10/

Comment: I am just testing now, but I did some research on 

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp

I have double borders on every td in the table, which allow the background color to come through (this is why I want some of them to look collapsed -- to occlude the background). I will have to test to be sure, but if I understand correctly, this will remove all of the double borders from my table :( Is there a way to set border-collapse to collapse on the very first two elements of every row?

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen To answer your question no. Border-collapse only works on table or inline-table. As to attaining your goal of double borders, you could try using `border:4px double black;` on your table like so: http://jsfiddle.net/h6DWg/3/ though it won't let the background color through.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen to do what you are talking about you would probably be best to add a div inside every cell and put your cell content in the div, give the div the background color you want and give it and cells borders.

Comment: Ahh, thankyou! Your answer deserves to be marked as the correct answer. I really didn't ask an easily answerable question! I shall mark it as correct and remove the secondary question from my question as that was poor form on my part

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen mocking the uncollapsed table style is hard to do especially if you want to merge two columns as one. May I ask why you need two cells to look like one?